# How to upload data permanently on google-colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I upload data using following code, the data vanishes once I get disconnected.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

Please suggest me ways to upload my data so that the data remains intact even after days of disconnection.

Answer (score 5):

I keep my data stored permanently in a .zip file in google drive, and upload it to the google colabs VM using the following code.

Paste it into a cell, and change the file_id. You can find the file_id from the URL of the file in google drive. (Right click on file -> Get shareable link -> find the part of the URL after open?id=)

```
#@title uploader
file_id = "1BuM11fJJ1qdZH3VbQ-GwPlK5lAvXiNDv" #@param {type:"string"}
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html


from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

# Replace the assignment below with your file ID
# to download a different file.
#
# A file ID looks like: 1gLBqEWEBQDYbKCDigHnUXNTkzl-OslSO

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

fileId = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id }) #DRIVE_FILE_ID is file id example: 1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE_vIKouTKyIDjEq
print(fileId['title'])  
fileId.GetContentFile(fileId['title'])  # Save Drive file as a local file

!unzip {fileId['title']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping data in GDrive is good (@skaem).

If your data contains code, I can suggest you to simply `git clone` your source repository from Github (or any other code versioning service), at the beginning of your colab notebook.

This way, you can develop offline, and perform your experiments in the cloud whenever you need, with up-to-date code.